# QSettings : is there a limit in .ini files line length?

Tags: c++, qt

I've tested it but did not reach the limit yet, so I was wondering if a .ini file, created using QSettings, has a line length limit ? Can't find any relevant information in the documentation.

Thanks

[EDIT] Relevant information found on [Qt's forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4525)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theoretical limit is the maximum length of a QString, which is held in an `int`. So the maximum is 2^31 - 1, over two billion characters (I'm not aware of any systems with a 16-bit `int` where Qt runs on.) However, you'd need at least 8GB of memory to hold such a long line (QString uses UTF-16 internally).

If you're interested about line lengths that range in the hundreds of characters rather than thousands or millions, you shouldn't have to worry. And besides, if you need ini files that have line lengths of thousands of characters, then I doubt that what you need is an ini file to begin with; ini files are to be used for settings, not as data storage.

Comment: Thanks ! I think it's 2^32-1 though ;)

Comment: @CTZStef It's an `int`, not an `unsigned int`, so it's really 2^31 - 1 due to the sign bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the limit is 200 characters.  One can change it with Compile-time option of -DINI_MAX_LINE=1024 etc.